# I have issues concatenating these strings

Tags: c++

I tried concatenating this strings together but i have been having difficulties. Please what should I do?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//Shorten the string identifier name
void Name_Input(){
    std::string st;
    //Let's create the name vector
    using V = std::vector<char>; //Aliasing string vector as V
    std::string First_name, Middle_name, Last_name;
    // Initializing a vector to hold the full names of the individual
    V Name() = Lastname + " " + First_name + " " + Middle_name
```

Comment: Please follow the instructions for [ask] questions, but first you should take the [tour] of stackoverflow.com, and read the [help].

Comment: Please follow @SamVarshavchik suggestions

Comment: Why are you using `std::vector<char>` to hold the result of the concatenation?

Comment: "i have been having difficulties" What does this exactly mean? Do you get any error? If so, please provide the error. Do you get different result than expected? Then please provide actual and expected results. Etc. etc., simply make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: @Sam Noted. Thank you all.

Comment: What makes you think you can assign a string to a vector of chars? They are distinct types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with string concatenation.

You are trying to assign a concatenated `std::string` to a `std::vector<char>`. That won't work, as `std::vector` does not have a constructor or an assignment operator that accepts a `std::string` as input.

It does, however, have a constructor, and an `assign()` method, that accept a range of iterators as input, eg:

```
std::string st = Last_name + " " + First_name + " " + Middle_name;
V Name(st.begin(), st.end());
```

```
std::string st = Last_name + " " + First_name + " " + Middle_name;
V Name;
Name.assign(st.begin(), st.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
V Name()
```

declares a function named `Name` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `V`.

```
V Name() = Lastname + " " + First_name + " " + Middle_name
```

attempts to assign a value to that function declaration, which the compiler ought to complain about. Not to mention that it’s missing a `;` at the end, so whatever comes after that line is also part of his expression.

Once that is fixed you’ll have to deal with copying the `std::string` object that that expression produces into an `std::vector<char>`.